# Linux Sees and Can Write to HDD but Windows Can’t

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

I have 3 NTFS partitions on my 2TB Seagate HDD. Only recently, my drives have stopped being recognised in windows.

I can look in device manager with hidden devices turned on and see that the device is installing when I boot. I uninstall it and reboot and the device is installed again. but not shown as connected.

[image]

ST2000... is my HDD.

I can boot into Arch Linux and can mount the drive with read and write access fine. I even ran ntfsfix to see if that did anything..

The drive shouldn't be dying. I have heard no clicking/loud noises and have only had it for a couple of years with minimal use.

Does anyone have any advice? As Windows cannot even see the drive I cannot run a check disk. I have already ran sfc with no results. I cannot even find the disk in recovery/partition software like MiniTool.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It sounds dumb but have you tried manually installing the Seagate drivers, it seems to be OS specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a little idea of what problem is. You can try by formatting the drive as NTFS again(so that the disk table rebuilds) and then try to see that drive in windows. Don't forget to take the backup.
I will suggest to format whole of the disk rather than a drive.

Comment: This seems like a little overkill.. Especially since I can read and write to the drive's partitions in other os's